# 503. That’s an error. There was an error. Please try again later. That’s all we know

Tags: google-chrome, mymaps

I'm using google mymaps. I have about 10 layers which represent about 12000 features.

Google says it can handle 10 layers and about 20000 features...

Sometimes the map is displaying or I'm getting this error:

```
503. That’s an error.
There was an error. Please try again later. That’s all we know.
```

Also, the navigation is very slow on Google Chrome compare to Internet explorer.

Anyways to fix this bug and issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

503 means server error on Googles side.

> 10.5.4 503 Service Unavailable The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of
>   the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition
>   which will be alleviated after some delay. If known, the length of the
>   delay MAY be indicated in a Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is
>   given, the client SHOULD handle the response as it would for a 500
>   response.

it could be your input is too difficult for the server to perform, and it crashes. You could try to reduce the complexity of your requests, or perhaps reduce the frequency of which you send the server a request.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, what google (or any company) says you can do is rarely the truth.  Its the same reason that car companies use miles-per-gallon to market how good their car is, when in reality this number came from lab testing where only the top performance was recorded as "best" when in reality the factors that reduce this efficiency are never considered until someone complains.  This applies to data limit claims as well.  Sure you can TRY to send that much data, but will it make it?  Usually not.  My rule is to take whatever they say you can do and figure out what 10% of that would be.  If 10% works consistently, then try 15 or 20% and continue this until you start getting more errors than you do valid responses.  Hope this helps!